# Valid way to put if statement into the phtml file within a javascript tag

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have the following code which needs to check whether a user is logged in to the system. The object it self is of following type:

```
$signInUser = new Zend\Session\Container("signInUser");
$signInUser = $signInUser->user;
```

Now what I do is check whether the user is logged in or not:

```
 if(<?!empty($signInUser['id'])?>)
            {
                mixpanel.track("landing_page", {
                    "brand":"<?= $this->config()['brandName'] ?>",
                    "journey": j,
                    "mission": m
                });
                console.log('user is logged in');
            }
            else{
                console.log('user is not logged in');
            }
```

Is this a valid way to mix JS and PHP code?? I noticed people do like this somewhere, but I'm not quite sure why;

```
<?=!empty(something)?>
```

Is my if statement above okay Is this the right way of doing it?

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

why ??

Comment: missing quotes `journey"`

Comment: I forgot to mention that the if statement is in the <script> tag. Is it okay?

Comment: its showing me an error in console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) @Devs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to fix the issues in the code:

```
if (<?php echo !empty($signInUser['id']) ? 'true' : 'false';  ?>)
{
    mixpanel.track("landing_page", {
        "brand":"<?php echo $this->config()['brandName']; ?>",
        "journey": j,
        "mission": m
    });
    console.log('user is logged in');
}
else{
    console.log('user is not logged in');
}
```

I suggest to avoid using short tags and write `<?php echo '...'; ?>` instead of `<?= ...?>`. There are [many different opinions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151661/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-tag-in-php) about this but at least you should be accurate with what you are doing.

In your example I think the issue is here `if(<?!empty($signInUser['id'])?>` What are you going to do here? Now it should output `if()` which is broken JS code and leads to JS error.

And the error should be like you show

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Comment: @perkes456 I suggest to accept the answer, else the question is shown in non answered. Other people might spend time checking the question when actually nothing more is needed here.

Comment: Yeah okay, sry I completely forgot to mark it as correct answer :)... I checked it as correct answer now :)